# Does Wagtail Cms support Google login and user login add session to

Tags: django, python-3.x, wagtail, google-signin, wagtail-pageurl

Is there is any way to add user login/google login and session in wagtail cms? 
tried adding projects during. how to implement security for wagtail.

Comment: Wagtail is Django so search for Django authentication apps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement this with a Django Social Authentication Plugin. Python Social App - Django is a good plugin to go with: https://github.com/python-social-auth/social-app-django.

Answer (score -1):

you can definaltly achieve this with djago-all-auth module https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html

Comment: AFAIK Wagtail is incompatible with allauth: https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/issues/1847.

Comment: huh this seam to be a old issue, at that time (2017) i didn't even know about Wagtail, btw both works fine, i've personnally added allauth to more than one site with Wagtail. It seem like wagtail still not inherit from django's site model it is not an issue. https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/blob/ef4b37cf5dd3e4b998a65487c58b043842792f4f/wagtail/core/models.py#L49

Comment: Well, I faced the problem described in the link I provided. I just wanted to reflect that I lost quite some time with allauth and then switched to social auth which worked flawlessly and your answer could mislead others. If you managed to get allauth working maybe provide an explanation on how you got it to work ? I’ll be glad to upvote this answer.

Comment: ok but just the fact that i've never got such issue with allauth... it's working on this site for example : www.d-fit.fr

Comment: As I'm in doubt - I will remove my downvote ;-)
Edit: mmm can't do that apparently :(

Comment: @JonathanLiuti here a video tutorial using django-allauth: https://youtu.be/2QLAc7RJ99s